# Calling an Oracle stored proc with "out" ref_cursor within a stored proc

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I am trying to basically call a set of Oracle stored procedures within a stored procedure. As long as my proc's are not returning a recordset and take "in" parameters, I am fine; however, one of the stored procedures has an "out" parameter of a sys_refcursor.  Calling the inner proc's also work fine but once I wrap them up with some partaining logic, I run into problems.

Specifically, I get the following error:

```
Error starting at line 2 in command: 
EXECUTE CRU_MY_PROCESS_EXPORT (1,'EAST',P_RECORDSET => :RC) 
Error report: 
Cursor is closed. RC
```

Here is the stored procedures:

```
1 create or replace PROCEDURE CRU_MY_PROCESS_EXPORT ( 
2   P_ID_NR IN NUMBER,
3   P_ENVIRONMENT IN VARCHAR,
4   P_RECORDSET OUT SYS_REFCURSOR ) AS
5
6    V_DB_SOURCE_ID NUMBER :=1;
7    V_REC SYS_REFCURSOR;
8
9   BEGIN
10     IF P_ENVIRONMENT = 'WEST' THEN
11      R_MY_PROCESS_SYNC_WEST(V_DB_SOURCE_ID, P_ID_NR);
12    END IF;  
13
14    IF P_ENVIRONMENT = 'EAST' THEN
15      R_MY_PROCESS_SYNC_EAST(V_DB_SOURCE_ID); 
16    END IF; 
17
18   --following proc call takes 'out' sys_refcursor as well
19   R_MY_PROCESS_EXPORT_ALL(V_REC);  
20     
21 END CRU_MY_PROCESS_EXPORT;
```

So, any help, advice would be greatly appreciated!

**Answer**
Thanks everyone who helped me think this through... changing the line 19 where the parameter is  "V_REC" to "P_RECORDSET"  was the answer.

Comment: You don't seem to be populating `P_RECORDSET`; should you passing that `R_MY_PROCESS_EXPORT_ALL` instead of `V_REC`?

Comment: @Alex Poole: I edited the proceedure above for reference.right...so, I tried passing my p_recordset to the R_MY_PROCESS_EXPORT_ALL(p_recordset) but it won't compile because this inner proc takes an 'out' parameter.

Comment: Ok...I feel silly now... I guess I am getting tired... I passed in the p_recordset from parameter above and now its working...ugh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see where you are doing anything with your `P_RECORDSET` parameter.  If the caller expects you to return an opened cursor, you need to return an opened cursor.

My hunch is that you don't want to declare a `v_rec` local variable and that you want to pass `p_recordset` to `r_my_process_export_all` which, I'm guessing, also has an `OUT` parameter of type `SYS_REFCURSOR`.

Comment: Hi Justin, I am not sure what I was thinking... I guess I have been playing around with this so long I had the wrong syntax...I just did as you suggested and it worked!  Thanks!